# Rails 4 - Using namespaced STI models with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, model, sti

My rails app has 5 user models that extend `User`. All of which have the namespace `User::UserTypeHere`. When I attempt to logout of my application, devise tries to access the models as if they belong to the top level namespace, and I get the following error:

```
"The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'SuperUser'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance..."
```

How do I set up my routes in a way that devise will recognize my namespaced models?

**routes.rb snippet**

```
...
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions, :passwords, :confirmations, :registrations, :unlocks]
devise_scope :user do

# authentication
unauthenticated :user do
  root to: 'users/devise/sessions#new', as: 'new_user_session'
end
authenticated :user do
  root to: 'application#index'
end

get '/login', to: 'users/devise/sessions#new', as: 'user_login_view'
post '/login', to: 'users/devise/sessions#create', as: 'user_session'
get '/logout', to: 'users/devise/sessions#destroy', as: 'destroy_user_session'

# registrations
get '/join', to: 'users/registrations#new', as: 'new_user_registration'
post '/join', to: 'users/registrations#create', as: 'user_registration'

# user accounts
scope '/account' do
  # confirmation
  get '/verification', to: 'users/confirmations#verification_sent', as: 'user_verification_sent'
  get '/confirm', to: 'users/confirmations#show', as: 'user_confirmation'
  get '/confirm/resend', to: 'users/confirmations#new', as: 'new_user_confirmation'
  post '/confirm', to: 'users/confirmations#create'

  # passwords
  get '/reset-password', to: 'users/passwords#new', as: 'new_user_password'
  get '/reset-password/change', to: 'users/passwords#edit', as: 'edit_user_password'
  put  '/reset-password', to: 'users/passwords#update', as: 'user_password'
  post '/reset-password', to: 'users/passwords#create'

  # unlocks
  post '/unlock', to: 'users/unlocks#create', as: 'user_unlock'
  get '/unlock/new', to: 'users/unlocks#new', as: 'new_user_unlock'
  get '/unlock', to: 'users/unlocks#show'

  # settings & cancellation
  # get '/cancel', to: 'users/registrations#cancel', as: 'cancel_user_registration'
  # get '/settings', to: 'users/registrations#edit', as: 'edit_user_registration'
  # put '/settings', to: 'users/registrations#update'
  # account deletion
  # delete '', to: 'users/registrations#destroy'
end
end
...
```

**user.rb (model)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**users/super_user.rb (model)**

```
class Users::SuperUser < User
    ...
end
```

**users/devise/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class Users::Devise::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the `type` column for your users needs to be `Users::SuperUser`, instead of just `SuperUser`, so that Rails autoload can find the correct class path.

Also, remember to restart your rails console & server when changing classes around, and don't keep old user instances with wrong values for type, as that will force rails to trigger an error when finding them